# Xamarin studio java.lang.outofmemoryerror

Tags: android, c#, visual-studio, xamarin

Доброго времени суток, помогите решить проблему. При запуске проекта вылетает ошибка java.lang.outofmemoryerror. На форумах предлагали следующий способ Options -> Android Build -> Advanced -> "Java Heap Size" and make sure that you set your heap size to atleast 1G. К сожалению не помогло, как решить данную проблему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: С хмарином не работал, просто интересно - что будет если воткнуть 8-10 Гбайт? Найти такое количество, при котором точно запускается и затем его уменьшить до нужного уровня.

Comment: 10 Гбайт я уже пробовал все равно выдает эту ошибку.